# How to notify EntityChangeSet in DomainServices Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, domainservices

First at all, my English is weak, hope you can understad!
I'm developing a silverlight application using DomainServices(DomainContext Class - Namespace:  System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client) to retrieve and update data.
I have some Properties:

```
DomainContextVBHS _Service = new DomainContextVBHS();


public int AddedEntitiesCount
{
    get{ return _Service.EntityContainer.GetChanges().AddedEntities.Count; }
}

public int ModifiedEntitiesCount
{
    get{ return _Service.EntityContainer.GetChanges().ModifiedEntities.Count; }
}
public int RemovedEntitiesCount
{
    get{ return _Service.EntityContainer.GetChanges().RemovedEntities.Count; }
}
```

How can i notify them on UI when _Service get any changes?

Comment: Are you looking for [RaisePropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.applicationservices.authenticationservice.raisepropertychanged(v=vs.91).aspx)? Oh and your english isn't bad at all. :)

Comment: Can you give me an example?(i try to find event to call RaisePropertyChanged but i didn't find anything ) and my project is net 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Sample code here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8424800/StackOverflowHasChanges.zip

I had a quick look at the source using the decompiler. There's no official way available. Fortunately, if you are willing to listen to all property changed events on all the inner entity sets, you should be able to achieve what you are after.

public class Sample : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

```
    SampleDomainContext _Service = new SampleDomainContext();

    public Sample()
    {
        _Service.Load(_Service.GetCustomersQuery());

        _Service.Customers.PropertyChanged += PropChanged;
        //_Service.Orders.PropertyChanged += PropChanged;
        // etc.
    }

    public int AddedEntitiesCount
    {
        get { return _Service.EntityContainer.GetChanges().AddedEntities.Count; }
    }

    public int ModifiedEntitiesCount
    {
        get { return _Service.EntityContainer.GetChanges().ModifiedEntities.Count; }
    }
    public int RemovedEntitiesCount
    {
        get { return _Service.EntityContainer.GetChanges().RemovedEntities.Count; }
    }

    public void PropChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var pc = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (pc != null)
        {
            pc(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AddedEntitiesCount"));
            pc(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ModifiedEntitiesCount"));
            pc(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("RemovedEntitiesCount"));
            // etc
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


}
```

Comment: i think about this(but that's long). Because i saw in DomainContext have a Property is "HasChanges". "HasChanges" listen all changes in DomainContext, so i want my properpty (like AddEntitiesCount ..v.v..) can do like that. do you have any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot listen on DomainContext.HasChanges. If you run the .NET Reflector on the assembly, you'll find that HasChanges will only fire once, and not on subsequent changes.

Comment: I know HasChanges only fire once, i mean my Property can "listen" like HasChanges - Any changes on DomainContext the HasChanges can changes from false to true when i make changes on any Domain like insert, delete Entity or Edit any Entity in that

Comment: If you listen on EntitySet<T>.HasChanges, it will fire every time a property is modified, object added, or deleted.

Comment: But, HasChanges will fire only 1 time.I try to count changes.
Example, i modified 3 records, ModifiedEntitiesCount is 3, but HasChanges fire only once with the first change

Comment: Sample code here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8424800/StackOverflowHasChanges.zip

Comment: I saw code from your project.
But how do you listen from ModifiedEntities?
I can do by add PropertyChanged event to each Entity inside. But my  data is about >20000 records>.< i dont want to loop 20000 to add event PropertyChanged